# java PosixFileAttributes return wrong atime and mtime

Tags: java, unix

My code is like

```
    String path = "/home/user/tmp/file1";

    Path p = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path);
    PosixFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(p, PosixFileAttributes.class);

    System.out.println("Last Modified Time: "+attrs.lastModifiedTime());
    System.out.println("Last Access Time: "+attrs.lastAccessTime());
```

The time returned by lastModifiedTime() and lastAccessTime() are 4 hours difference with the correct one.

The output is 
Last Modified Time: 2014-06-25T12:50:31Z
Last Access Time: 2014-06-25T18:26:07Z

stat file1 produce:
Access: 2014-06-25 14:26:07.870281008 -0400
Modify: 2014-06-25 08:50:31.922861913 -0400
Change: 2014-06-25 08:50:31.922861913 -0400

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A time like

```
2014-06-25T12:50:31Z
```

is in UTC (that's the Z at the end), so it may be off according to your time zone.